# Store list of licensed states in MySQL without using JSON type?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Scenario:

I am creating a database and tool to track subconsultants used by my employer and what states they are licensed in. Some of these companies are licensed in all 50 US states, so rather than have 50+ boolean columns I made a json column to store the abbreviations of the states they are licensed in.

Problem:

Long term, I don't think using json format is the best option since it will make importing data more difficult, but I can't come up with a better way to do this so wondering what the community suggests.

Thank you!

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of representing a many-to-many relationship is with another table.

Hypothetical example:

```
CREATE TABLE licensed (
  company_id INT,
  state CHAR(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (company_id, state),
  FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company(company_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (state) REFERENCES state(state)
);
```

(I'm making some assumptions about your company and state tables.)

You would insert one row into this table for each state licensed for a given company. So up to 50 rows for each company. Even if you track 1,000 companies, this will still be a small table from MySQL's perspective.

This is generally more flexible than either storing 50 columns, or using JSON or a comma-separated string, or any other kind of aggregated list format.

Comment: would it be better for computing power to have 50 columns for each state as a boolean, or to have potentially 50 rows for each company?

Comment: It depends on the query. For example, search for a company that is licensed in Maryland and Kentucky. Do you have an index on those two out of your fifty columns? If not, it'll be bad for performance because you may have to do a table-scan.

Comment: 50 columns isn't good, performance-wise, for anything.  The above is the correct answer if you want purely relational data.  It is flexible, so you can have additional data on each state (like the full name, agency contacts, etc.) and you could expand beyond states to cover different kinds of licenses.